# JQuery calling global from local

Tags: jquery, chart.js

This is slightly complicated to say but hopefully you'll catch my drift. (fingers crossed)

I'm trying to call a `global var` in `JQuery` from a file called `data.js` which contains lists of data for `chart.js`

In my `data.js` list I have `data_china` and another like `data_UK`. You call that specific `data_(name)` from a var passed into that page. and apply that `global var` to a `local var` so I can call it later for `chart.js`.

Hopefully my code below clears up some confusion.

What I am asking is it possible to call global var like I have or is there a more efficient way to do it?

**Code**:

```
            $.getScript("js/data.js" )
              .done(function() {
                  var name = "data_" + urlpar.toLowerCase() + "";
                  var data = name;
                  alert("Data name is:" + data + "")
              })
              .fail(function() {

                var data = {
                labels: ["FR", "Fl", "FC", "P", "TR", "TX"],
                datasets: [

                    {
                        label: "2014",
                        fillColor: "rgba(128,0,128,0)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(128,0,128,1)",
                        pointColor: "rgba(128,0,128,1)",
                        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(128,0,128,1)",
                        data: [16, 17, 15, 15, 18, 16]
                    },
                    {
                        label: "2013",
                        fillColor: "rgba(80, 219, 102,0)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(80, 219, 102, 1)",
                        pointColor: "rgba(80, 219, 102, 1)",
                        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(80, 219, 102, 1)",
                        data: [10, 12, 10, 11, 7, 9]
                    }
                ]
            };

            });
```

**EDIT:**

var name is equal to `data_china`. `data_china` is a `global var` in `data.js` i need name to call it.

My Data looks like this, I need to call specific data depending on the page, each page has its own data_(name). but I need a way to select a pages specific data set.

If I goto page `site.html?name=china` i need it to load china's data if it's `site.html?name=uk` then I need it to load UK's data_uk and apply that global var to a local var. There is a hundred different site names so I need a way to automate this.

You call charrt.js's data set by creating a var of `var data = "";` so I need var data = data_china; (or data_(name of country/place)) depending on the page.

**Data.js**:

```
data_china = {
                labels: ["FR", "Fl", "FC", "P", "TR", "TX"],
                datasets:
                [

                    {
                        label: "2014",
                        fillColor: "rgba(128,128,128,0)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(128,128,128,1)",
                        pointColor: "rgba(128,128,128,1)",
                        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(128,0,128,1)",
                        data: [16, 17, 15, 15, 18, 16]
                    },
                    {
                        label: "2013",
                        fillColor: "rgba(102, 219, 102,0)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(102, 219, 102, 1)",
                        pointColor: "rgba(102, 219, 102, 1)",
                        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(80, 219, 102, 1)",
                        data: [10, 12, 10, 11, 7, 9]
                    }
                ]
            };
data_uk = {
                labels: ["FR", "Fl", "FC", "P", "TR", "TX"],
                datasets:
                [

                    {
                        label: "2014",
                        fillColor: "rgba(128,128,128,0)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(128,128,128,1)",
                        pointColor: "rgba(128,128,128,1)",
                        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(128,0,128,1)",
                        data: [16, 17, 15, 15, 18, 16]
                    },
                    {
                        label: "2013",
                        fillColor: "rgba(102, 219, 102,0)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(102, 219, 102, 1)",
                        pointColor: "rgba(102, 219, 102, 1)",
                        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(80, 219, 102, 1)",
                        data: [10, 12, 10, 11, 7, 9]
                    }
                ]
            };
```

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: If you have var data_china declared as global inside data.js file, yes you should be able access it's value after using $.getScript

Comment: @DanielRosano Yes i know, i can access it but i need to call it specifically from  the other 99 `data_name` depending on the  `site.html?name=china`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it right, what you need is to call it with [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) on the `window` object like:
`window[name]`

Comment: That is brilliant thanks very much, It got the job done.